# Yii2 Dynamic Relational Query Junction with Sort uses 2 queries instead of a JOIN, why?

Tags: mysql, activerecord, yii2, database-performance

I'm working with Yii2 Relational Database / Active Query Models and I ran into an issue trying to use the magic method `getModelName()` with `$this->hasMany()->viaTable()` to set the relation while trying to sort by a `sort` column in my junction table.

First I tried to just add my `->orderBy()` clause to the main query:

```
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,
        ['id' => 'categoryId'])
            ->viaTable('{{kits_x_categories}}',
                ['kitId' => 'id'])
            ->orderBy('{{kits_x_categories}}.sort asc');
```

That didn't work as expected and upon further digging I found out that this results in two separate queries, the first one selects my category Ids into an array, then uses said array for a `WHERE IN()` clause in the main (2nd) query to get the actual models that are related.

My first thought was to use the 3rd `function($query) {}` callback parameter of the `->viaTable()` call and putting my `$query->orderBy()` clause on there:

```
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,
        ['id' => 'categoryId'])
            ->viaTable('{{kits_x_categories}}',
                ['kitId' => 'id'],
                function($query) {
                    return $query->orderBy('{{kits_x_categories}}.sort asc');
                }
            );
```

However, all that did was return the category ID's in my desired order but ultimately had no effect on the main query that does the `IN()` condition with said ids since the order of the ids in the `IN()` condition have no effect on anything.

Finally, I ended up with this which lets it do what it wants, but then forces in my join to the main query with the `IN()` condition so that I can have the main query sort by my junction table sort column. This works as desired:

```
    return $this->hasMany(Category::class,
        ['id' => 'categoryId'])
            ->viaTable('{{kits_x_categories}}',
                ['kitId' => 'id'])
        ->leftJoin('{{kits_x_categories}}', '{{kits_x_categories}}.categoryId = {{categories}}.id')
        ->where(['{{kits_x_categories}}.kitId' => $this->id])
        ->orderBy('{{kits_x_categories}}.sort asc');
```

This results in 2 queries.

First the query gets the category ids from the join table:

```
SELECT * FROM `kits_x_categories` WHERE `kitId`='49';
```

Then the main query with the `IN()` condition and my forced join for sort:

```
SELECT `categories`.* FROM `categories` 
    LEFT JOIN `kits_x_categories` ON `kits_x_categories`.categoryId = `categories`.id 
    WHERE (`kits_x_categories`.`kitId`='49') AND (`categories`.`id` IN ('11', '7', '9')) 
    ORDER BY `kits_x_categories`.`sort`
```

So here is my actual question... This seems largely inefficient to me but I am by no means a database/SQL god so maybe I just don't understand fully. What I want is to understand.

Why does Yii do this? What is the point of making one query to get the IDs first, then making another query to get the objects based on the ids of the relation? Wouldn't it be more efficient to just do a regular join here? Then, in my opinion, sorting by a junction sort column would be intuitive rather than counter-intuitive.

The only thing I can think of is has to do with the lazy vs eager loading of data, maybe in lazy in only gets the IDs first then when it needs to load the data it pulls the actual data using `IN()`? If I used `joinWith()` instead of `viaTable()` would that make any difference here? I didn't dig into this as I literally just thought of that as I was typing this.

Lastly, In this scenario, There is only going to be a few categories for each kit so efficiency is not a big deal but I'm curious are there any performance implications in my working solution if I were to use this in the future on a different model set that could have thousands+ of relations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yii 2 does that:

1. To support lazy loading.
2. To support cross-database relations such as MySQL -> Redis.
3. To reduce number of edge-cases significantly so internal AR code becomes less complicated.

Comment: Hi Sam! Thank you for the reply. If I wanted, is there a way to configure the relationship as "always eager" so that it would join by default or no? Do you think my solution above is "good"? or would you have done it differently?

Comment: See https://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/834/relational-query-lazy-loading-and-eager-loading-in-yii-2-0#why-not-use-join. Yii 2 can't do that in a single query and that's done on purpose. These 2 queries are eager loading. Non-eager one would do N+1 queries instead.

Comment: That's not the best possible way to select data compared to a single SQL query but it's not too bad either. Both queries are pretty performant.

Comment: Thank you for the insight :)

Answer (score 0):

3rd party software is usually designed to get you started with databases.  But then they fall apart when the app grows.  This means that you need to learn the details of the underlying database *in addition to* the details of the layer.

Possibly this specific issue can be solved by improving the indexes on the many-to-many table with the tips here:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table
This, of course, depends on whether the layer lets you tweak the schema that it created for you.

If there is a way to write "raw" SQL, that might let you get rid of the 2-step process, but you still need to improve the indexes on that table.

Comment: I appreciate taking a stab at this but Yii's active record implementation has more going for it just "getting started" stuff. There are very powerful relational implementations that the whole application database philosophy is designed around. Sure I could accomplish what I'm asking by doing raw queries but then I'd be short changing my self out of all the great relational tools provided by Yii moving forward.